# Cannot Delete Unused Images From Newly Deleted Product Magento

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I have Installed this [Image Clean extension](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/defcon2/extension/1147/image-clean) to delete unused images from magento.

Before I delete the 512 products, I installed this extension and it works. It deleted 852 unused images. After that, I delete this 512 products and it was successful however when I tried to use again this extension, It cannot delete the unused images from the newly deleted product.

I am using magento 1.9.2.0, I already refresh my cache and re-index it. I also delete in the directory the var/cache and var/session.

Is there a way I can delete this unused product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello I just installed and tested this extension and found that After deleting product you must need to click on "**Refresh**" Button in Image clean extension item list page.

I tried with two products and worked for me. Let me know if you are getting any error or some wrong behavior of system.

Comment: Thanks @Sarfaraz bheda for answer, yes I have clicked the refresh button but there are no product images displayed.

Comment: Ok. You can use this shell script to clean unused images https://bitbucket.org/magpleasure/imagecleanup

Comment: Thanks @Sarfaraz bheda, I'll try this.